# SwiftUI EditButton() bug

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm presenting a List inside a modal. If I'm inside a NavigationView the EditButton its totally broken.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var showSheetView = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Button(action: {
            self.showSheetView.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "bell.circle.fill")
                .font(Font.system(.title))
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheetView) {
            SheetView()
        }
    }
}
}

struct SheetView: View {
@State private var myArray: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach(myArray, id: \.self) { item in
                    Text(item)
                }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                })
            }
        }
        .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
    }
}
}
```

If I remove the NavigationView where i present from, then at first it seems to work, the second time i present it gets broken again.

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State var showSheetView = false

var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.showSheetView.toggle()
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "bell.circle.fill")
                .font(Font.system(.title))
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheetView) {
            SheetView()
        }
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you describe what you think is broken and what desired effect is. Both movies look about the same.

Comment: So I expect when tapping edit button to enter edit mode. That means the red buttons for each row appears. Makes sense ?

Comment: Look on the second image, the appear the first time I present modally the screen.

Comment: What happens if you associate the edit button with the list instead of the vstack?

Comment: The same bug...

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 12.0 / iOS 14. Don't you use some Xcode beta?

Comment: @Asperi you are right. Seems a bug on Xcode beta.

Comment: This bug happens without the `.sheet` modifier as well. EditButton is totally broken when used inside a simple `NavigationView > List > ForEach > Text` structure. I'm using macOS Big Sur with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

Comment: Did anyone found a solution for this? I'm using XCode12 as well

Comment: Refer to the similar question below: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76149780/editmode-and-editbutton-unexpected-behavior-when-embedded-in-navigationview/76680297#76680297

Answer (score 7):

Manually handling the `editMode` works for me on macOS Big Sur with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1.

I also had a problem of `EditButton` showing "Edit" again in an edit mode when I rotate the simulator, and the below solution solves it as well.

The following solution uses a custom `EditButton` struct that handles a manual `editMode` binding.
First the custom `EditButton`:

```swift
struct EditButton: View {
    @Binding var editMode: EditMode

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            switch editMode {
            case .active: editMode = .inactive
            case .inactive: editMode = .active
            default: break
            }
        } label: {
            if let isEditing = editMode.isEditing, isEditing {
                Text("Done")
            } else {
                Text("Edit")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the above `EditButton` is straightforward:

```swift
struct SheetView: View {
    @State private var myArray: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three"]
    @State private var editMode = EditMode.inactive

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach(myArray, id: \.self) { item in
                        Text(item)
                    }.onDelete(perform: { indexSet in
                    })
                }
            }
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton(editMode: $editMode))
            .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
            .animation(.spring(response: 0))
        }
    }
}
```

The `EditButton` in the trailing navigation bar item handles the `@State private var editMode` kept in `SheetView`.
This `editMode` is then injected into the inner views using the environment `.environment(\.editMode, $editMode)`.
For the animation effect of the edit mode transition, I found `.spring(response: 0)` most appropriate.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
.navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton())
```

you could try:

```
.toolbar { EditButton() }
```

I had the same problem and this worked fine for me.

Comment: It works for me, but it is weird, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, in iOS 16.0

```swift
struct MyEditButton: View {
  
  @Binding var editMode: EditMode
  
  var body: some View {
    Button {
      switch editMode {
      case .active: editMode = .inactive
      case .inactive: editMode = .active
      default: break
      }
    } label: {
      if let isEditing = editMode.isEditing, isEditing {
        Text("Done")
      } else {
        Text("Edit")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ContentView: View {
  
  @State var editMode: EditMode = .inactive
  
  @State var list = ["A", "B", "C"]
  
  var body: some View {
    Form {
      Section(header: HStack {
        MyEditButton(editMode: $editMode)
          .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
          .overlay(Text("LIST"), alignment: .leading)
      }) {
        List {
          ForEach(list, id: \.self) { value in
            Text(value)
          }
          .onDelete(perform: deleteSection)
          .onMove(perform: moveSection)
        }
      }
    }
    .environment(\.editMode, $editMode)
    .padding()
  }
  
  func deleteSection(at offsets: IndexSet) {
    list.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
  }
  
  func moveSection(from source: IndexSet, to destination: Int) {
    list.move(fromOffsets: source, toOffset: destination)
  }
}
```

[image]